# ASP.net Multiple database link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I have 2 windows Azure Database serveur with same tables scheme on them but with differents data.
In my asp.net site I connect with my first db like this:
**Web.config**

```
<add name="FirstDBContext" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
```

**DatabaseContext.cs**

```
public class FirstDBContext: DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Data> Datas{ get; set; }
}
```

**DatasController.cs**

```
private UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
public ViewResult Index()
{
   return View(db.Datas.ToList());
}
```

As you can see I have my db set in the code. How can I change this to be able to change dynamically to one DB to another with a drop list for example ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks it's a great idea. To answer you correctly.
I can now change the target db and I can list the entries. But when I want details on an entry it returns an error.
I have for testing :

```
private UsersContext db = new UsersContext("db1");

public ViewResult Index()
{
   db = new UsersContext("db2");
   return View(db.Users.ToList());
}
```

This returns the good db2 list but when i go on details it fails and returns an error.

**Here is the answer of the problem :** [Changing dbContext at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366811/changing-dbcontext-at-runtime)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the name of the connection string when initializing the UsersContext

For example if you have the following connection stirngs

```
<add name="csFirstDB" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
<add name="csSecondDB" connectionString="..." providerName="..." />
```

You can change your UsersContext to

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext {
    public UsersContext (string connectionName) : base(connectionName){ }
}
```

Now when you initialize the UsersContext class object, pass in the connection string name and it will refer to that particular db.